# Thread.Sleep in AsyncTask catch block

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm currently facing an issue where the first call of the Thread.sleep method is properly executed, but the second one in the catch block isn't. I removed the try catch block of the Thread.sleep call for the sake of readability, there are no raised exceptions. The AsyncTask instantly proceeds to onPostExecute, the second Thread.sleep call isn't run.

Where's the problem?

```
private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        System.out.println("PreExecute done.");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... urls) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        return "something";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know it will only run in the `catch` block if there is an `Exception`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The `catch` block code is only executed if an instance of the [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) class (an [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) in your case) is raised during the `try` block's execution. It looks like you might be looking for the `finally` keyword.
The following snippet of code will call the specified function, ignoring any raised exceptions and sleeping the current thread for 1000 milliseconds.

```
 try {
      exceptionsRaisingMethod();
 }
 finally {
      // always sleep
      Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
```

The snippet above is literally just a better way to do the following:

```
 try {
      exceptionsRaisingMethod();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
      // do nothing
 }

 Thread.sleep(1000); // always sleep
```